# Deleting files genereated by CronJobs

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-server

A month ago i had created a cronjob which used to execute a php file using wget command. Today i was shocked to see that there are thousands of files created like Master.8787009 , Master.879889

Now the Master was my php file name which i was executing using  wget.
I found that i should have used wget -q command to prevent any output from wget which i did now

But how do i safely remove all these files which were created ? 
All this files are stored under /home/username folder on my Live Server and fear of losing some important data is in my mind

I just need a SAFE command which will delete all files that has word Master in it's name from folder /home/username

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.. I would have to run the following command

```
  find . -name "filename*" -delete
```

. = current directory

-name = match name of file

"filename*"  = name of file that consist pattern 'filename'

-delete = Delete those files

It worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

If you cd into the correct directory you should be able to find to list all the files with

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "Master.*"
```

The -maxdepth 1 mean that this is not recursive so will only find files in the current directory.

When you have checked that it is only finding the correct files the you can remove the files as follows:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "Master.*" | xargs rm
```

Always good to check first!